# How do I add Apache Batik and OpenePnP libraries in my project

Tags: java, svg, batik

[Here is problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMtwT.png)

[Please guide me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1IHi.png)

I tried to add libraries which I download and it didnot work.
can someone help me to solve this problem

Comment: are you using maven ?

Comment: Please [don't upload text as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13447). Edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. Also see [ask]: A screenshot of an IDE is not a proper problem description. Check [mcve] for a description of what is required to help, and what will help others coming after you finding the same, or a similar problem and its solution

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The tag [tag:STL] is wrong here. Read the descriptions while choosing tags.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using maven :

For For Apache Batik:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
  <artifactId>batik-all</artifactId>
  <version>1.13</version>
</dependency>
```

For For OpenPnP:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.openpnp</groupId>
  <artifactId>openpnp-lib</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Apply the import as required.

```
import org.apache.batik.dom.svg.SVGDOMImplementation;
import org.openpnp.model.LengthUnit;
```

If you are not using maven:

1.Download the latest version of the libraries from the Apache Batik website (https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/) and the OpenPnP website (http://openpnp.org/).

2.Add the libraries to your project's classpath. This will typically involve adding the libraries to your project's build path or referencing them in your build tool's configuration files.

Doing above must help you in general.